# Grails Release Plugin Maven Deployment doesn't update <latest> tag in maven-metadata.xml consistently

Tags: maven, grails, artifactory

## Background

I have two Grails applications, both running Grails 2.3.6 with the release plugin installed (`build ":release:3.0.1"`).

I have a jenkins CI server setup to automatically pull the projects from source control and deploy the war to artifactory. From there, it can be automatically deployed to our tomcat server by a script.

For one application, the maven-metadata.xml file generated by Artifactory contains a `<latest>` tag, which specifies which of the versions of my application is the latest one.

## Problem

My problem is, the other application *doesn't* have a `<latest>` tag, even though it's using the exact same command to deploy to our Artifactory repository-- `grails maven-deploy`. The BuildConfig.groovy files are basically identical.

This is a problem because I need that `<latest>` information to be available for my deployment script.

From what I've [read around the web](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/23778606-Why-are-the-latest-and-release-tags-in-maven-metadata-xml-not-being-updated-after-deploying-artifact), the maven-metadata.xml file is generated by maven 2 only when the `-DupdateReleaseInfo=true` flag is set. However, I can't see any place that the working application is passing this flag to maven during the build.

I've tried the fix suggested on [this thread](http://forums.jfrog.org/maven-metadata-xml-for-artifacts-seem-corrupt-td5336149.html)-- namely,

- Making sure that deploying user has "annotate" permission
- Maven Snapshot Version Behavior = "Deployer"

But my second application *still* doesn't get a `<latest>` tag added to its maven-metadata.xml.

Comment: which version of Artifactory are you using?

Comment: Artifactory version: 3.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured out that I can easily just pass `-DupdateReleaseInfo=true` to the `grails maven-deploy` command as an additional argument, and that forces maven to update the `<latest>` tag in maven-metadata.xml. I'm not sure why it is doing it sometimes and not others, but at least it works!